# How do you get Plotly to adjust plot size based on screen resolution in a Streamlit app?

Tags: plotly, streamlit

I'm building a `streamlit` app with `plotly` graphs. However, I'm finding it hard to set a dynamic plot width in the `plotly` figures (I expect the app to be viewed in multiple resolutions).

Is there a way to tell `plotly` to use 100% (or 80%, etc.) of the width (whatever number of pixels that might be).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use the `use_container_width` argument of [`st.plotly_chart`](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/charts/st.plotly_chart):

```py
st.plotly_chart(fig, use_container_width=True)
```

Comment: `st.plotly_chart(fig, use_container_width=True)` isn't working for me

Comment: Happy to help, but can you share more context?

Comment: Adding the setting as recommended had no effect on my figure widths. I'm using plotly figures

Comment: is there any hack to automatically adjust the height ?

Answer (score 3):

```
fig.update_layout(height=800)

st.plotly_chart(fig,use_container_width=True,height=800)
```

I used this and it worked fine.
I had to use both only then it worked.